# How can I summarize a column that shows the mean difference in R?

Tags: r

```
tableData <- tibble(Fruits = sample(c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'), 30, T),
                        Ripeness = sample(c('yes', 'no'), 30, T),
                        Mean = ifelse(Ripeness == 'yes', 1.4 + runif(30), 1.6 + runif(30))) %>% 
 add_row(Fruits = "Peach", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 5)

get_t_test_pval <- function(formula){
  tryCatch({t.test(formula)$p.value}, error = function(cond) NA)
}

tableData %>% 
  group_by(Fruits) %>% 
  summarise(t_test_pval = get_t_test_pval(Mean ~ Ripeness))
```

The following code summarizes the table so that p-values are evaluated for each fruit. Is it possible to also add a column that shows the mean difference (ie mean of yes ripeness - mean of no ripeness) to each fruit? With a trycatch enabled as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is after grouping by 'Fruits' `summarise` by the taking the difference of `mean` of 'Mean' where 'Ripeness' is 'yes' with that of 'no', while applying the OP's function to get the 't_test_pval'

```
library(dplyr)
tableData %>% 
  group_by(Fruits) %>%    
  summarise(Meandiff = mean(Mean[Ripeness == 'yes'])- 
        mean(Mean[Ripeness == 'no']), 
       t_test_pval = get_t_test_pval(Mean ~ Ripeness))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Fruits Meandiff t_test_pval
#  <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 Apple     0.122       0.435
#2 Banana    0.167       0.327
#3 Orange   -0.306       0.216
#4 Peach   NaN          NA
```

Comment: Why not just `tableData %>% 
  group_by(Fruits) %>% 
  summarise(t_test_pval = get_t_test_pval(Mean ~ Ripeness),
            Meandiff = mean(Mean[Ripeness == 'yes'])- mean(Mean[Ripeness == 'no']))`

Comment: @ValeriVoev yes, that was updated, but I was just testing for any issues with `mutate`